# Run F# 3.1 on Visual Studio 2012 (not express)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#

I was wondering if it is possible to run F# 3.1 on Visual studio 2012? if possible then what is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK it's not official supported (you can always *replace* fsi and fsc) but you can get VS2013 express with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run the 3.1 Visual Studio integration components (e.g. the language service, project system, editor integration) on VS 2012, no.  So any bug fixes or features there will not be available.

But you can still build, run, debug projects against the F# 3.1 compiler and runtime from VS 2012.  Install the latest release (3.1.1) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41654).  Create a new project in VS 2012, and edit the `.fsproj` file to point at the 3.1 `Microsoft.FSharp.targets` file and the 3.1 version of `FSharp.Core.dll`. I haven't tried this personally, but I think it should work reasonably well.

And in case cost is a factor preventing moving to VS 2013, note that starting with 3.1.1, Visual F# does support VS Desktop Express.