# Compatibility .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5. Could not load file or Assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0.'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, f#-3.0, fparsec, math.net

I want to use the library Math.NET Symbolics in the F# project.
But when I run simple code:

```
open MathNet.Symbolics
open MathNet.Symbolics.Operators
```

...

```
let expr = Infix.parseOrThrow("sin(x) * y")
let symbols = Map.ofList [ "x", Real 2.0; "y", Real 3.0 ]
let res = Evaluate.evaluate symbols expr
```

I have:

```
Could not load file or Assembly ' FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\" or one of the dependent components. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I created a topic in the forum [Math.NET](http://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/math-net-symbolics-for-wpf-f-project/115)

During the discussion, I thought it was impossible, because I only have .Net 4.5 and VS2012 (therefore I can't use F#3.1).

But I can't understand, if everything works in .Net 4.0, why I can not normal use in .Net 4.5. What about compatibility version?

Question: is it even possible? And, if possible, how?

**Edit:**

When app.config has:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.3.5.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
```

This code works fine:

```
let symbols = Map.ofList [ "x", Real 2.0; "y", Real 3.0 ]
let x = symbol "x"
let y = symbol "y"
let res = Evaluate.evaluate symbols (sin(x) * y)
```

But I need to use a parser for mathematical expressions. Therefore, this option does not suit me.

**Update:**

**Answer:**

After an unsuccessful compile Visual Studio was changed reference to the FSharp.Core from package folder on a standard FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0.
When I set the property "Copy Local"  = "true" - problem was solved.

Now code

```
let expr = Infix.parseOrThrow("sin(x) * y")
let symbols = Map.ofList [ "x", Real 2.0; "y", Real 3.0 ]
let res = Evaluate.evaluate symbols expr
```

gives another exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$MathNet-Symbolics>.$Infix'
 threw an exception. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime
```

I was looking for a mistake where it was not. The problem is not dependence. Because code without using FParces worked!

[On the page for the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FParsec) is written as follows:

> "This package uses the basic “low-trust” configuration of FParsec,
>   which does not use any unverifiable code and is optimized for maximum
>   portability. If you need to parse very large files or if you employ
>   FParsec for performance-critical jobs, consider using the alternate
>   “Big Data Edition” NuGet package (see
>   nuget.org/packages/fparsec-big-data-edition)."

So, I changed FParsec on [FParsec (Big Data Edition)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fparsec-big-data-edition) and everything works!

P.S.
My attempts to change the binding redirect did not make sense =) just write:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
```

Comment: https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html

Comment: @Hans Passant, I read it a few times. And looked other similar questions on SO. Sorry, but I can't understand how I can help this information.

Comment: Which version of `FSharp.Core` *do* you have?

Comment: For a great overview of how various versions of `FSharp.Core` matches .NET versions, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20362049/126014

Comment: For information on how to redirect assembly bindings for `FSharp.Core`, see this article: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431

Comment: @ Mark Seemann , Sorry, I've read them before, but not found the answer.

Comment: @Mark Seemann, I tried to change, but have not achieved a normal result. Updated the question, added some information.

Answer (score 3):

If Math.NET was compiled against 4.3.1.0, and you're stuck with Visual Studio 2012, which comes with 4.3.0.0, you have two options that I can think of:

- Grab the Math.NET source code, change it to target 4.3.0.0, and compile it.
- [Install F# 3.1 into VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25163461/24380)

But you should really think about upgrading.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have no way to update Visual Studio. I found the answer to my question, without recompiling Math.Net.

Comment: Since it costs nothing to install a newer version of F# into Visual Studio, and it costs nothing to download the Community Edition of VS 2015, I have to assume it's your employer preventing you from using the tools you need to do your job. That doesn't reflect well on your employer.

Comment: At the moment, programming for me is only a hobby . I don't have the ability to update Windows7, which will allow to install at least VS2013. But I plan to do this at the end of the month. Although, of course, the update creates some additional difficulties.

Comment: @FoggyFinder - Why would you need to update Windows 7? Is it because VS 2015 requries Win7 SP1? That service pack is more than 5 years old...

Comment: I have quite an old laptop. And I'm afraid that if I change OS something goes wrong. I can't risk it now.